# Is there a way to force enable quicktime?

Tags: language-agnostic

So I'm trying to play music on a webpage, but whenever it plays for the first time, you have to go through a short but annoying process of enabling quicktime for the website.

Is there either:

- Another way to play music (a different music player) that can still be invisible and plays immediately?
- A way to force enable quicktime when they get to the site?

So yeah, please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I just embedded an invisible youtube player. Works decently.